# Dplyr select based on multiple strings in a column

Tags: r, regex, dplyr

I have a data frame containing following columns:-

```
 sample.data


 a_b_c d_b_e r_f_g c_b_a
1     1     1     1     1
2     2     2     2     2
3     3     3     3     3
4     4     4     4     4
```

How do I select only columns that contain both let's say "a" and "c" in the column name?

Comment: could you please let us know your expected output.

Comment: The output data.frame should contain only columns:- a_b_c and c_b_a. Because both these columns contain string "a" and string "c".

Comment: yes, it contains only the columns.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To select variables that contain `a` and `c` we could do:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  select(matches("(a.*c)|(c.*a)"))
```

> ```
>   a_b_c c_b_a
> 1     1     1
> 2     2     2
> 3     3     3
> 4     4     4
> ```

Note that var `a_a_e` is not selected because it doesn't contain `c` and var `c_f_g` is not selected because it doesn't contain `a`. Column names with two `a`'s and two `c`'s will not be selected either as seen with var `a_a_e`.

We could also use `str_subset`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

df %>% 
  select(str_subset(names(df), "(a.*c)|(c.*a)"))
```

---

Data:

```
df <- data.frame(
  a_b_c = 1:4,
  a_a_e = 1:4,
  c_f_g = 1:4,
  c_b_a = 1:4
)
```

Comment: This is precisely what I was looking for. Thanks.

Comment: Np, happy to help

Answer (score 2):

Try `df %>% dplyr::select(matches("(a|c)"))`

```
library(dplyr)
df <- data.frame(
  a_b_c=1:4,
  d_b_e=1:4,
  r_f_g=1:4,
  c_b_a=1:4
)
```

Results

```
> df %>% dplyr::select(matches("(a|c)"))
  a_b_c c_b_a
1     1     1
2     2     2
3     3     3
4     4     4
```

Comment: Seems like the OP might require that both letters appear, since they say "a and c", not "a or c". They haven't clarified yet, though...

Comment: Its "a" and "c" that I am trying to get.

Comment: @MadhukarJha I guess `df %>% select(intersect(contains("a"), contains("c")))` in that case.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this is what you are looking for:

```
  a_b_c <- c(1,2,3,4)
     d_b_e <- c(1,2,3,4)
    yy <- cbind(a_b_c, d_b_e)
    > yy
     a_b_c d_b_e
[1,]     1     1
[2,]     2     2
[3,]     3     3
[4,]     4     4
 yy <- as.data.frame(yy)
 yy
  a_b_c d_b_e
1     1     1
2     2     2
3     3     3
4     4     4
 y <- yy[which(names(yy) %in% "a_b_c")]
> y
  a_b_c
1     1
2     2
3     3
4     4
```

In your example, you can use this:

```
 y <- sample.data[which(names(sample.data) %in% c("a_b_c","c_b_a" )]
```

Comment: No that is not what I am looking at.

Comment: Ok, could you please write your expected output.

Comment: "In your example, you can use this:

 y <- sample.data[which(names(sample.data) %in% c("a_b_c","c_b_a" )]"  This is specific example. I want to select all the columns that contains "a" and "c" which means I want "a_c_b_d" as well as "u_a_d_c" and so on.

Comment: you meant you want it as general. Ok.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see how it works under the hood, use the following **function**:

```
contain_both <- function(data_frame, letter_a, letter_b) {
    j <- 0
    keep_columns <- NULL
    for(i in 1:ncol(data_frame)) {
    has_letters <- unlist(strsplit(names(data_frame)[i], '_'))
    if(is.element(letter_a, has_letters) && is.element(letter_b, has_letters)) {
    j <- j + 1
    keep_columns[j] <- i
    }
    }
    return(data_frame[, keep_columns])
    }
```

**Data**:

```
df <- data.frame(seq(1:4), seq(1:4), seq(1:4), seq(1:4))
names(df) <- c('a_b_c', 'd_b_e', 'r_f_g', 'c_b_a')
```

Just pass in your **data frame**, along with your **2 letter choices**:

**Usage**:

```
contain_both(df, 'b', 'c')
```

[image]

Comment: It would have been great to see something more simple i.e using native function but this does the trick.